# Add resizable watermark and resize video same time

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark, ntfsresize

I want to add a gif watermark to different videos with different sizes actually I want to combine these 2 commands in once

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:00 -i in.ts -ignore_loop 0 -i log.gif -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*15/50':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=0:0:shortest=1" output.mp4
```

and resize result to this

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf scale=426:240 output2.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it after the overlay.

```
[vid][wm]overlay=0:0:shortest=1,scale=426:240
```

You may wish to add the setsar filter after the scale to ensure correct aspect ratio.